# size of this struct does not add up

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)
>   [sizeof(struct) returns unexpected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596428/sizeofstruct-returns-unexpected-value)

I wrote a program to find the size of the following struct abc.

a. The inbuilt sizeof() operator mention the size of this struct to be 40 when it is actually 32? Also I tried subtracting the addresses to determine this and it also resulted in 40.

b. When I comment out "char g[3];" inside struct abc, the size of abc = 32.
This also doesn't make any sense to me. Shouldn't this be 28?

c. Why do I need the casting to "unsigned int" ? If I do not do the casting, I get the following compilation error message. Isn't &a[0] actually an address (which should be an int)?

size_of_struct\size_of_struct.cpp(24): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'abc *' to 'unsigned int'

Info:
I am running win 7, 64 bit system. MS visual studio compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

struct char_three{
    char a[3];
};

struct int_three{
    int a[3];
};

struct abc 
{
    int a; // 4 bytes
    double b; // 8
    void *ptr; // 4
    char g[3]; // 4 due to padding ?
    int c[3]; // 12
}; // Total size of struct - 31 / 32.

int main () 
{
    abc a[2]; 
    unsigned int add0, add1;
    add0 = (unsigned int) &a[0];
    add1 = (unsigned int) &a[1];
    printf("add1 of a is :%x add0 is :%x\n", add1, add0);

    printf("size of struct abc : %d\n", add1-add0);
    printf("size of int: %d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("size of double: %d\n", sizeof(double));
    printf("size of void ptr: %d\n", sizeof(void *));
    printf("size of 3 char: %d\n", sizeof(char_three));
    printf("size of 3 int: %d\n", sizeof(int_three));
    printf("size of a: %d\n", sizeof(a));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

O/P:
add1 of a is :51f828 add0 is :51f800
size of struct abc : 40
size of int: 4
size of double: 8
size of void ptr: 4
size of 3 char: 3
size of 3 int: 12
size of a: 80
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Read about padding [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Comment: You can perform pointer arithmetic on the addresses of the various member variables to see where the compiler has added padding.

Comment: FYI, on MS compilers, `#pragma warning(default:4820)` will enable a warning indicating where padding is added in the middle of a structure, but padding is also added to the end of a structure so arrays of the structure will maintain aligned accesses.  In this case 4 bytes were added to the end to make the total size 40, so the double would always be 8-byte aligned in arrays of this structure.

Answer (score 0):

You must not rely upon the sizeof() of structs explicitly. It's implementation-defined whether the compiler introduces padding and if so, where it does. If you use a GCC-compatible compiler and don't mind about other toolchains (wait, there are other toolchains?), you can use `__attribute__((packed))` to tell the compiler not to add padding to your struct at all.